# Removing duplicate keys from two dictionaries (Python 3.6)

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries.

```
d1 = {(1,1):1 , (2,1):1 , (2,2):1 , (1,2):1}
d2 = {(1,2):1 , (2,2):1}
```

I want to delete all elements of `d2` from `d1`. Therefore, if there is a repeated KEY in both dictionaries, that KEY should be deleted from d1.

`newd1 = {(1,1):1 , (2,1):1}`

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
for key in d2:
    d1.pop(key, None)
```

Comment: I think this is the most efficient way of doing this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
{k:v for k, v in d1.items() if not any(str(k2) in str(k) for k2,v2 in d2.items())}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `del` to delete key from dictionary:

```
d1 = {(1,1):1 , (2,1):1 , (2,2):1 , (1,2):1}
d2 = {(1,2):1 , (2,2):1}

for key in d2:
    if key in d1:
        del d1[key]

print(d1)
```

and the result will be:

```
{(1, 1): 1, (2, 1): 1}
```